# How can you create Appointments (not meetings) in Outlook with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to create Outlook Calendar appointments via a Powershell script. The below script works, it adds events to the calendar. But it adds an unsent Meeting Invitation to the calendar, not an Appointment. When I set the **MeetingStatus** to **zero** (or any other value besides 1) -- which is supposed to indicate a non-meeting event, aka an Appointment -- nothing gets added to the calendar.

```
$meeting = $ol.CreateItem('olAppointmentItem')
$meeting.Subject = 'New Years Day'
$meeting.Location = 'Office Closed'
$meeting.ReminderSet = $false
$meeting.MeetingStatus = 1
$meeting.Start = '1/1/2021 8:00:00 AM'
$meeting.Duration = 540
$meeting.BusyStatus = 3
$meeting.Categories = 'Holiday'
$meeting.Send()
```

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A friend pointed out the solution, so I'll document it here for completeness:

I was using `Send()` but to save an appointment (MeetingStatus = 0) I need to instead use `Save()`

Made the change and it works like a charm.